# PHP <<< (multi-line handler?) question

Tags: php, date, multiline

I have some code as follows:

```
$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT
    *
FROM
    names
WHERE
    create_date > date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
QUERY
```

How can I put the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in there without breaking out of the `<<<` statement?

Comment: What you call the "multi-line handler" (<<<) is actually called a "heredoc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store that piece of code in a variable and use substitution.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT
    *
FROM
    names
WHERE
    create_date > $now;
QUERY;
```

(Example: http://www.ideone.com/pKSVF)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = <<<QUERY
SELECT
    *
FROM
    names
WHERE
    create_date > $date
QUERY
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#PHP